# tensorflow - how to add an if statement?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
result = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: np.matrix(np.array(values[0][1]))})

if result > Z:
    print('A')
else:
    print('B')
```

Yet when trying to run this I get:

```
if result > Z:
  File "/home/John/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 578, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

How to fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
def getCertitude1(result):
    return (Z/result)*100

def getCertitude2(result):
    return (result/Z)*100

result = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: np.matrix(np.array(reps[0][1]))})

if result is not None:
    a = tf.cond(tf.less(result, Z), lambda: getCertitude1(result), lambda: getCertitude2(result))     
    print("a: " + str(a))
```

results in `a: : Tensor("cond/Merge:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)`

Comment: Have you thought about reading the error message?

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't know what is the correct way to proceed based on the error message

Comment: `cost` is not translating to a boolean variable, that's why.

Comment: Literally do what the error message tells you `[...] use TensorFlow ops [...]`

Comment: @HenriMenke I tried that as well, but there was still smth wrong, see my update

Comment: Have you even read the documentation on `tf.cond`... It's all there: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond

Comment: @BramVanroy yes, I have.

Comment: @BramVanroy updated my answer

Comment: `a` not is also a tensor. You could get a value of `a` by calling `sess.run(a, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) objects can't be used with regular python objects and functions. That's how tensorflow is designed. `if/else` blocks, `for`, `while` and other python stuff should be replaced with appropriate tensorflow operations like `tf.while_loop`, `tf.cond` and so on. These operations operate with **tensors** which are the main tensorflow objects, and could not be used with python objects.

The only way to get a python object from tensor is to call `tf.Session` object on this object. Thus, when you are calling `sess.run()` you get python object (more precisely, **numpy** one). Apparently, `Z` is a `tf.Tensor`, and it shouldn't be mixed with python object `result`.

You could either evaluate `Z` with another `sess.run()` and then switch to regular python operations, or properly use `tf.cond` and create a subgraph based on the values of `cost` and `Z` which are both tensors.